# SQLite vs MemSQL vs other SQLAlchemy compatible in memory databses

Tags: sqlite, in-memory-database, singlestore

What is the recommended in-memory database which connects to SQLAlchemy?

Requirements:

- Connects to SQLAlchemy.
- Minimal memory usage when empty (it will store <50MB).
- Easy to work with (e.g. Kafka vs RabbigMQ: Kafka requires much more user input/setup).
- Reliability in terms of the database going down unexpectedly.
- Can be accessed by multiple read applications.
- Shareable across a local network.

The two databases I've researched are SQLite and MemSQL.
Some points so far:

- MemSQL requires 8GB of memory, although I am unsure how much it uses when empty?
- MemSQL has replication however only in the paid version and not the free community version.

Input from users who have used these solutions or others is very valuable. Which solution would you recommend?

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking, what databases SQLAlchemy connects to? SQLAlchemy is the *tool* that connects to databases. If it doesn't support a database now, it may do so in the future

Comment: BTW SQLite isn't an in-memory database. Did you mean *embedded* database? You are comparing completely different things - SQLite can handle small amounts of data. MemSQL or SQL Server or any other database with in memory capabilities can handle as much data as there is memory and then some.

Comment: I had a look at what databases SQLAlchemy connects to here http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/index.html. However later found that MemSQL which is not listed in the previous link also connects to SQLAlchemy: http://docs.memsql.com/4.1/concepts/connecting/#sqlalchemy. My understanding is that SQLite by default stores on disk however can be configured to in memory: https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html

Comment: You are comparing skateboards and trucks. You can't compare an embedded database with a *distributed* database.

Comment: Aside from being distributed and having replication, what makes SQLite a skateboard and MemSQL a truck? SQLite's max database size is 140TB (point 14 on this page: https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html). I noticed that SQLite is not a client/server database. Would this prevent SQLite being used by multiple read applications and/or across a local network? Is there another database you would recommend for such requirements?

Comment: @Dave SQLite is file-based. You won't be able to use it across a network without writing your own sort of "server" interface for it. See SQLite's [When To Use](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) page, eg. point 1 under "Checklist for Choosing The Right Database Engine."

Comment: You should understand what a database is and what is the difference between file based, embedded databases, and database servers. All non-embedded databases cover your requirements. There *are* file-based databases that allow multi-user access, eg ... Access. Picking one database at random, without understanding the pros/cons, can easily doom your project

Comment: >> •MemSQL has replication however only in the paid version and not the free community version         Does that mean you cannot consider commercial products?

Comment: Commercial products are fine provided that they are priced to be accessible